# Cannot send data larger than 64 KB with pipes in C

Tags: c, memory, pipe, size, buffer

I am trying to send usr/share/dict/words file (which is around 971 KB) from parent to two child processes via named pipes. However, output is empty and I did not get any errors.I waited for a minute but nothing changed. Program works fine with 10KB of data that I tried with. I know  that pipe buffer size is 64KB but can someone explain what is wrong with my approach:

Here in the code:
  - ptr_child_1 refers to shared memory pointer, 1 MB of shared segment mapped.
  - fd and sd are pipes, file is the file pointer

Code is long  that is why I did not paste all of them. I just wonder how I should send that large file

Parent write:

```
mknod(FIFO_1, S_IFIFO | 0666, 0);
mknod(FIFO_2, S_IFIFO | 0666, 0);

// open pipes
int fd = open(FIFO_1, O_WRONLY);
int sd = open(FIFO_2, O_WRONLY);

char str[3000];
while(fgets(str, sizeof(str), file) > 0)
{
   // write all lines of file
   write(fd, str, strlen(str));
   write(sd, str, strlen(str));
}
 // send EOF explicitly
        write(fd, "\0", 1);
        write(sd, "\0", 1);
        // close file and pipes
        close(fd);
        close(sd);
        fclose(file);
```

Child read:

```
    int num;
    char s[3000];
    while((num = read(fd, s, sizeof(s))) > 0)
    {     
        sprintf(ptr_child_1, "%s", s);
        ptr_child_1 += num;
    }
    // close pipe
    close(fd);
```

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing all of each file. My first suggestion is to get the return value from all of those calls (read, write, mknod, open, etc.) and start printing error messages with perror() when something goes wrong.

Comment: Where is the child made in relation to the parent? Make sure you create the child before the parent starts writing to the FIFO. Otherwise your parent will write 64K and then block until the pipe is emptied. If you create the child before the parent tries to write then the child is able to read from the pipe even as the parent is writing to the pipe, so the size limit isn't an issue.

Comment: It seems likely that you're trying to write to the FIFOs before you have let the children loose to read from the FIFOs.  There is a 64 KiB limit on the buffer size for pipes and FIFOs in modern systems — it was just 5 KiB once upon a long time ago.  We need to see the process control code.

Comment: `sprintf(ptr_child_1, "%s", s);` expects `s` to be a _string_ .  It is not (resulting in UB) as it can lack a _null character_.  Suggest `sprintf(ptr_child_1, "%.*s", num, s);` instead.